# Power Automate flow - attachments in the array

Tags: email, attachment, powerapps, power-automate

I have a small issue. I need to take non-pdf attachments from the email and take these attachments into an array and send the email back (only with no pdf attachments in the email, PDF attachments I send separately, 1 pdf = 1 email).

[image: Apply to each]

The biggest issue is - separate emails with pdf work well, the biggest issue is with other attachments in the array - I cannot open them.

[image: PDF vs non pdf]

[image: sending other attachments - issue with the array]

[image: cannot open the file from array]

Be able to open attachments from email with multiple attachments.